# Bijection between sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) Can we establish an bijection between the set of sequences strictly crescent of length $5$ with terms from $1$ to $100$, and the sequence of $5$ non-zero numbers witch the sum of the terms is minor or equal $100$?

b) Define a bijection between the binary sequences of length $n$ with exactly one block "$01$" and the set of natural solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n-2$.

These are two questions of a book of discrete mathematics I'm reading, and only those two questions I couldn't get to an answer. Any help?

Comment: I am guessing that the phrase "strictly crescent sequence" means that the sequence is strictly increasing.  Assuming so - Hint: if you have a sequence $\{a_0,a_1, \cdots, a_5\}$ with $a_0 = 0$, you could define $\{b_1, \cdots, b_5\}$ by $b_n = (a_n - a_{n-1}).$

Comment: for b, did you try to create a few examples of sequences avoiding $01$? If so can you slice it into blocks, and what can you say about these blocks (in the perspective of finding $4$ integers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$)?

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you! I understood perfectly.